# Corollary to Markov's Inequality

Tags: probability

Here is a particular case of Markov's Inequality that I failed to prove:

> Let $X$ be a non-negative integer-valued random variable with $\mathbb{E}(X)\leq m$ then $$\mathbb{P}(X=0)\geq 1-m$$

Does anyone has an idea how to prove this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$m\geq\mathsf EX=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\mathsf P(X=n)\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathsf P(X=n)=\mathsf P(X\geq1)=1-\mathsf P(X=0)$$

Comment: Hence it is not a corollary to Markov's Inequality.

Comment: To find it as corollary of Markovs inequality subtitute  $a=1$ in $aP(X\geq a)\leq EX$ and work out.